# aspxgridview 2 context menus

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

Can we have 2 context menus for devexpress aspxgridview, one context menu for rows and one for columns headers?
If yes, then how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

> **Yes**, you can do it..

Follow this - [How to display a popup menu for grid column headers or rows](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E723.aspx)  nice DevExpress example, which demonstrate that you are looking for.

Check this markup in `AspxGridView` for `multiple context menu`..

```
<dxm:ASPxPopupMenu ID="pmColumnMenu" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="pmColumnMenu">
        <Items>
            <dxm:MenuItem Name="cmdShowCustomization" Text="Column Chooser...">
            </dxm:MenuItem>
        </Items>
        <ClientSideEvents ItemClick="function(s, e) {
            if(e.item.name == 'cmdShowCustomization')
            grid.ShowCustomizationWindow();
    }" />

</dxm:ASPxPopupMenu>
   <dxm:ASPxPopupMenu ID="pmRowMenu" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="pmRowMenu">
         <Items>
             <dxm:MenuItem Text="Export to PDF" Name="cmdExport">
             </dxm:MenuItem>
         </Items>
     <ClientSideEvents ItemClick="function(s, e) {
        if(e.item.name == 'cmdExport')
            alert('Export simulation.');
    }" />
```

For more help go through this [search result](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=context%20menu%20on%20rows&p=T4%7CP5%7C57&d=762).

Hope this help...